# Data at the root level is invalid - at the end of file that I'm creating

Tags: c#, xml, exception, serialization

I'm trying to serialize a class:

```
 File.Delete("fisierXML.xml");
 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("fisierXML.xml",FileMode.Create))
 {
     System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer s = 
         new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
     s.Serialize(fs, myClassInstance);
 }
```

Everything works fine everytime the amount of data I want to write on the xml file is the biggest - and when I try to write not so much data on the file - an error seems to occur: "Data at the root level is invalid."

When I open the XML file - there is no error and the XML file seems OK!

I've tried deleting the file - or FileMode.Create - or FileMode.Truncate - but everytime is the same problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get that during serialize? Or deserialize?

Comment: that sounds very odd. Stacktrace?